# How to convert "$#" from bash to Powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell

I have to change a bash script into a PowerShell script, but I dont really get the condition in the `if`-statement.

```bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    name='plmapp-all'
else
    name="$1"
```

Does somebody know what's `$#` and how this statement would look like in PowerShell?

Comment: # -Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal like `if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "NO PARAMETER PASSED"
fi`

Comment: `$#` would be `$args.Count` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

`$#` is an [internal bash variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) that holds the number of arguments passed to a script. Its PowerShell equivalent is `$args.Count`. `$args` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) holding a list with the arguments passed to the script (like `$@` in bash). Since PowerShell is working with objects you can obtain the argument count directly from the `$args` array without the need for an additional variable.

The whole expression would look like this in PowerShell:

```
if ($args.Count -gt 0) {
    $name = 'plmapp-all'
} else {
    $name = $args[0]
}
```

You could simplify that to

```
if ($args) {
    $name = 'plmapp-all'
} else {
    $name = $args[0]
}
```

because PowerShell [interprets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) non-empty arrays as `$true` and empty arrays as `$false` in a boolean context.

An even more streamlined alternative would be:

```
$name = @($args + 'plmapp-all')[0]
```

Since `$args` is always an array the `+` operator appends the string to that array, then the index operator selects the first element from the result array.

```
[] + 'plmapp-all'              → [ 'plmapp-all' ]
[ 'something' ] + 'plmapp-all' → [ 'something', 'plmapp-all' ]
```

Comment: *because PowerShell interprets non-empty arrays as `$true`* `[bool](,$false)` or `[bool](,$null)` or `[bool](,@())` or `[bool](,'')`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Edge cases notwithstanding. ;þ